# Remote Desktop connection from outside network stopped working

Tags: certificate, firewall, remote-desktop

I connect from my home PC (Win10 Pro) to my office PC (Win10 Ent.) regularly.
Now I can't RDP from my home computer to office directly. But I can connect from home PC to my office server and from the office server to my office PC. Both office computers are on the same corporate network and a home PC is outside the corporate network (connected via OpenVPN to the corporate network).

There is no IP specific firewall rule blocking the connection (I changed no settings and one day just couldn't connect to the office PC any more). I can connect to my office server, but not to the office PC.

Comment: Why downvote (reason)? Any improvements can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several trials commended by [MicroSoft answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/rdc-not-connecting-outside-network/686866fc-5d3d-4547-9b39-b88b4e10439d?auth=1&rtAction=1502576573037) and one of the posts directed me to check the RDP certificates.

My office PC was publishing several Remote Desktop certificates, from which one just expired and RDP from my home PC stopped working. The new RDP certificate was issued too, but it wasn't trusted on office PC as soon as it wasn't in Trusted Root CAs. When I entrusted the certificate and rebooted the office PC, RDP started working.

The question would be why there was an RDP certificate without the proper trust?